# How can I escape the key-modifier characters in Texter?

Tags: escape-characters

In [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/238306/lifehacker-code-texter-windows)'s *script* mode, the ! character is used to denote the Alt key.

I want the script to actually *type* a ! character -- how can I escape this so it will work?

In the *text* mode (not script mode) it works, of course, but I want to use it in combination with Tab and Enter keystrokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the old Texter page on Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/software/texter/lifehacker-code-texter-windows-238306.php) you just wrap the special characters in curly brackets to escape them.

Comment: Brilliant! Why wasn't this obvious to me? Thanks!